# I am getting error -1100 for NSURLConnection in iOS?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, nsurlconnection

I have started getting the error code -1100 for NSURLConnection in the latest version of iOS on my project made with Ionic v3.

> 2017-09-22 09:40:53.495836-0400 Aqua Hydration[11721:2415097] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100

I am assuming it is a reason my app is displaying nothing after the splash screen. I am running it on a physical iPod touch connected through a usb. I am also getting the same error on the emulators.

Comment: If it helps, -1100 is `NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist`.

Comment: That may help... let me look into it... xcode error logs are so unhelpful

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this probelem by:

1. Reinstalling npm.
2. Removing the npm modules packages.
3. Running npm update.